# How to dump json output to the file using jq?

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to copy certain `key:value` pairs from a `json` file to normal text file using `jq` within a `bash` script. I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TestConfig="[...]/config_test.json"

#create new empty file if it doesn't exist
echo -n "" > test_sample.txt

echo "X=$(jq -r .abc $TestConfig '.' > test_sample.txt)"
echo "Y=$(jq -r .xyz $TestConfig '.' > test_sample.txt)"
```

But this copies only "values" (only values of .abc and .xyz) to test_sample.txt. But I am expecting:

```
cat test_sample.txt
X=test1
Y=test2
```

The config_test.json is:

```
{
    "abc": "test1",
    "xyz": "test2"
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what needs to be changed to have expected outcome? The `.json` file is quite big and I am extracting more key:value pairs from it. Hence any looping way to reduce `jq` operation time would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing.

Comment: May I know why the OP is down voted? I can improve the question if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to convert a JSON object's fields to raw text, following a `key=value` structure.

Use `to_entries` to decompose the object, iterate over its items with `[]`, and output a formatted string using the `.key` and the `.value`. Make sure the output is raw text using `-r`:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value)"' config_test.json > test_sample.txt
```

```json
abc=test1
xyz=test2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7JHP5QczMQt)

Comment: Hello @pmf, thanks for the quick response. But can I use `to_entries[]` to filter keys? For example, I want to dump only value of abc from `.json` file. Like, `test_sample.txt` should contain only `abc=test1` instead of all entries.

Comment: I tried with `jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.key.abc).value' config_test.json > test_sample.txt` But this leads to `jq: error (at config_test.json): Cannot index string with string "abc"`

Comment: @Preeti You can filter with `select` like so: `jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.key == "abc") | "\(.key)=\(.value)"'`. However, this form is more useful if you rather wanted *all but* some key (e.g. `... select(.key != "xyz") ...`). If you just want to have one or a few keys, rather pick them directly as in `jq -r '("abc", "def") as $key | "\($key)=\(.[$key])"'` using a variable, or in case of just one use `jq -r '"abc=\(.abc)"'` naming the key explicitly (albeit twice).